# hope + future perfect

Tags: future-perfect

Can we use future perfect to express our hope?

For example:

> 1 I hope that by the end of the year, I will have been accepted in one of the top schools in the country.

If it is a valid structure, how does it differ from "hope + simple future" in conveying meaning? For example:

> 2 I hope that by the end of the year, I will be accepted in one of the top schools in the country.

Comment: simple future is simple future, whereas future in the past means you are looking at something as past **in the future**. [correction: I hope that by, not I hope that until]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of those sentences are correct and natural, and they serve the same function. I cannot think of a context where they would have different meanings, or where one would apply and the other wouldn't, so you might consider them to be functionally the same.

There's probably some prescriptivists that would argue you should use future perfect with "by", but in natural conversation or writing, either would work.